# QtWebEngine doesn't support JavascriptCanCloseWindows

Tags: qt

In [`QtWebkit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum), using `QWebSettings` class, I could enable like the permission to close the window using the JavaScript command `window.close();`:

```
 setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanCloseWindows, true);
```

But in [`QtWebEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html), such an attribute doesn't exist: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum

How to allow JavaScript to close any `QWebEngineView` using `window.close()`?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this attribute doesn't exist anymore in the Qt WebEngine.

However, you can close any views using the signal [windowCloseRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#windowCloseRequested) from your QWebEnginePage, and connecting it to a slot where you close the window. There is an example of use in the [Demo Browser example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-demobrowser-example.html), in the file [webview.cpp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-demobrowser-webview-cpp.html):

```
connect(page(), &WebPage::windowCloseRequested, this, &QWidget::close);
```

Comment: I already use this, this is just to capture the "soliticitation", this is not what `JavascriptCanCloseWindows` does, not even in "QtWebkit". `JavascriptCanCloseWindows`. allows any closing action, even if it is not user interaction, close the browser. For example if `window.close()` is in a `onclick=` it will work with or without `JavascriptCanCloseWindows`, but if `window.close()` is inside "setTimeout" it will only work if `JavascriptCanCloseWindows` is set to `true`. This response only works if it is a window generated via `window.open`, which is normal behavior.